# Node.JS callback after getting return value from function

Tags: node.js, callback

In my main.js file I have this object:

```
var options = {
    foo: 'bar',
    foofoo: 'barbar',
    accountBalance: getBalance()
};
```

function `getBalance()` makes POST request on a server that gets money balance of a user account. After balance is returned I need to call another function `myFunc()` something like this:

```
var options = {
    foo: 'bar',
    foofoo: 'barbar',
    accountBalance: getBalance() //when accountBalance is returned, call myFunc() from here
};

function muFunc(){
//do something
}
```

getBalance function:

```
var request = require('request');
function getBalance(){
        request(POSToptions, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return body.balance;
         } else {
           console.log("ERR" + body);
        }
     });  
  }
```

I know I need to use callback function but I can't still wrap my head around that concept. Can someone help me and ideally provide explanation on how to create a callback function? Thanks!

Comment: If `getBalance` sends POST request it's async function, then `accountBalance` is a promise or undefined (if you use callback). Could you show how `getBalance` function looks like?

Comment: I added getBalance function to my post

Comment: You incorrectly define `options` object. So as `getBalance` is async function, you can't get the response immediately, so `options.accountBalance` will be undefined. What about calling `muFunc` from `getBalance` function, just pass it as callback: `getBalance(myFunc)` and call it there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, we need to make `http call` using one of the properties in the `options` object (which in this case is `accountBalance` property referring to a function).

Because `http request` in asynchronous in nature, we will get a callback once the request is served.

My solution is to add one more property in the options object which will get fired once the callback is triggered.

In the below example I have used `http get call` but ideally it should remain the same for any of the http verbs.

Check out the following example -

```
(() => {

    function getBalance() {
        //do your stuff here
        //then ajax call
        $.get('URL', (response) => {
            //call callback function in http response callback.
            options.callback(response);
        });
    }

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    let options = {
        foo: 'bar',
        foofoo: 'barbar',
        accountBalance: getBalance,
        callback: callback
    };

    //make ajax call here
    options.accountBalance();

})();
```

I have added another property called `callback` in the `options object` which holds the `callback function reference`.

> EDIT - I have replaced the AJAX callback with a setTimeout function to simulate the async nature

```js
(() => {

    function getBalance() {
        //do your stuff here
        //then ajax call
      setTimeout(() => {
          let response=  {
              data: "foo"
          }
          options.callback(response);
      }, 1000);
    }

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }

    let options = {
        foo: 'bar',
        foofoo: 'barbar',
        accountBalance: getBalance,
        callback: callback
    };

    //make ajax call here
    options.accountBalance();

})();
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you explain littlebit what's happening here? Thanks

Comment: `options.accountBalance` is undefined in OP and your examples.

Comment: I declared options before declaring the functions! My bad :| I have edited the answer now. Thank you @alexmac

Comment: It's still incorrect. Read my comment in OP question.

Comment: I have now verified it with a code snippet! Silly me

Answer (score 0):

your getBalance() return before executing getBalance()

You can use async/await

```
// npm install--save request
// npm install--save request-promise

var request = require('request-promise');

var getBalance = async () {
    return await request(POSToptions);
}


const muFunc = async () => {
    //do something
    var options = {
        foo: 'bar',
        foofoo: 'barbar',
        accountBalance: await getBalance()
    };
}
```